# Variable returning undefined when calling against a custom object, fine otherwise

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have a custom object that looks like

```
var locationsMap = {
            "obj1":[1],
            "obj2":[7],
            "obj3":[21]               
}
```

I can call this custom object like:

```
var loc = "obj2";
alert(locationsMap[loc][0]);
```

And this works fine in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu99Z/); however, when I embed this logic within my code within NetSuite, loc becomes undefined:

```
nlapiLogExecution('debug',"Location: "+ loc); //works fine
nlapiLogExecution('debug','Location: '+locationsMap[loc][0]); //throws exception
```

In the NetSuite debugger:

```
$ nlapiLogExecution('debug','Location: '+locationsMap[loc][0]);
> TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined
```

Why is loc showing as undefined when I call it via the `locationsMap` object, but not 
undefined when I call it by itself?

--Edit--

Calling `nlapiLogExecution('debug','Location: '+locationsMap['obj2'][0]);` works as expected.

--Edit 2--

I ended up abandoning this approach due to these issues, although I am still interested in finding out why this behavior is being experienced.

Comment: Because `loc` isn't the `undefined` part. The undefined part is locationsMap[loc] - what is the value of `loc` in your example with NetSuite? Particularly, what does this line `nlapiLogExecution('debug',"Location: "+ loc); //works fine` log?

Comment: locationsMap does not have the key, is it called before it is set?

Comment: That line references the specific location, `pLocation 1: myRedactedLocation`, which in locationMap would have myRedactedLocation instead of say obj1

Comment: @epascarello locationsMap is defined at the start of the function, where these calls are occurring below the definition. The map is fully fleshed out at initialization

Comment: Could you add the real `locationsMap` and `loc`?

Comment: Is there something else in the variable? `nlapiLogExecution('debug',"Location: "+ (loc==='obj2'));` or `nlapiLogExecution('debug',"Location: "+ escape(loc));`

Comment: @epascarello spaces, hiphens and parens,

Comment: does nlapiLogExecution('debug',"Location: "+ (loc==='obj2')); return true?

Comment: @epascarello yes it returns true

Comment: What if you assign `locationsMap[loc][0]` to a variable and use that in your call?

Comment: @Craig Same exception: `Cannot read property "0" from undefined`

Comment: The easiest thing would be to stop this code in the JavaScript debugger - not the NetSuite debugger - and look at the variables there. You will soon discover what is wrong. Put a `debugger;` statement just before the line in question and start looking at variables when it stops on that line.

Answer (score 0):

I threw this in the NetSuite debugger and SuiteCloud IDE debugger and all came back correct.  Time has solved the problem.

```
var locationsMap = {
            "obj1":[1],
            "obj2":[7],
            "obj3":[21]               
};
var loc = "obj2";
nlapiLogExecution('debug',"Location: "+ loc); 
nlapiLogExecution('debug','Location: '+locationsMap[loc][0]); 

debug   Location: obj2  10/30/2014 20:05:41.303
debug   Location: 7 10/30/2014 20:05:43.284
metrics usage 0, time 20096 10/30/2014 20:05:43.284
```